# Can I use Chinese characters in CSS class names?

Tags: css, chinese-locale

Is it possible to use Chinese class names for my CSS classes? I'm trying to get the Chinese word with jQuery and then create `img` elements with classes named by the Chinese words.

I have for instance a file named `2020_Cars_哈喽_1.jpg`, and I created a code that takes the year, the category (Cars), and the Chinese word which is the name of the album, and creates an `img` element with classes according to the file name in order to filter the images later.

I have an example [here](http://oren.byethost13.com/) where you can see the categories which translated to classes without any problem, and the `%46%bd%` which are Chinese words that I could not transform successfully into a class name.

Any suggestions please?

The jQuery code which takes the file name and split it into classes:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: dir,
     success: function(data){
         $(data).find("a:contains(.JPG)").each(function(){
             // will loop through
             var images = $(this).attr("href");
             var splittedName = images.split('_');
             var classesToAdd = 'thumbnailpic';
             for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
                 classesToAdd+=' '+splittedName[i];
             }

             if(years.indexOf(splittedName[0])===-1){
                 years.push(splittedName[0]);
             }
             if(categories.indexOf(splittedName[1])===-1) {
                 categories.push(splittedName[1]);
             }
             if(albums.indexOf(splittedName[2])===-1) {
                 albums.push(splittedName[2]);
             }

             $('.gallery').append('<img class="'+classesToAdd+'" src="'+dir+'/'+images+'"'+'>');

         });

         for(var a=0;a<years.length;a++){
             $('.years').append('<div id="filter-button" class="filter-select" >'+years[a]+'</div>');
         }

         for(var b=0;b<categories.length;b++){
             $('.categories').append('<div id="filter-button" class="filter-select">'+categories[b]+'</div>');
         }

         for(var c=0;c<albums.length;c++){
             $('.albums').append('<div id="filter-button" class="filter-select">'+albums[c]+'</div>');
         }
         hideBigPic();
         $('.filters').fadeIn(1000);
         $('.gallery').fadeIn(1000);
     }
 });
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Chinese characters as class names and selectors.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.tomato {
  background: tomato;
}

.蓝色 {
  background: navy;
}
```

```html
<div class="蓝色"></div>
<div class="tomato"></div>
<br>
<button onclick="console.log(document.querySelector('.蓝色'))">Find Element</button>
```

But it looks like the real question here is how do you turn URL encoded characters (%46 etc) back into real characters and for that you need [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

```js
console.log(decodeURIComponent('%E8%93%9D'))
```

Hope this answers all of your questions.